# How to Write a Nested For Loop in One Line Python with File Url and File Name

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested

```
 data = json.dumps({'conf':{a:b for a in table_name for b in file_url}})
 print(data)
```

I have 2 files in file_url.

```
sales_dy_20221022.csv
sales_wk_20221022
```

I have 2 table names in table_name

```
sales_dy
sales_wk
```

If I write the code like the above I get the result below.

```
"conf": {
"sales_dy": "sales_dy_20221022.csv",
"sales_wk": "sales_dy_20221022.csv"
}
```

How can I change the code and get the result below?

```
"conf": { "sales_dy": "sales_dy_20221022.csv", "sales_wk": "sales_wk_20221022.csv" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right path, use `zip`.
ex.  `data = json.dumps({'conf':{a:b for a,b in zip(table_name,file_url)}})`